# How do I enable the simulator for iPod touch (7th generation) in Xcode 15?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ipod-touch, xcode15

I can't get the iPod touch simulator in Xcode 15 to work. It just says "No Runtimes".

1. I've opened the "Manage Run Destinations" window in Xcode 15
2. I've pressed the plus to "Create a new simulator"
3. In Device Type Drop Down - I select "iPod touch (7th generation)"

Though after that the "OS Version" below says "No Runtimes".
I've checked "Download more simulator runtimes" but the only ones available are "tvOS" and "watchOS" ones.

How can I find the right runtime for the iPod simulator?

Answer (score 0):

The iPod touch 7th generation supports only up to iOS 15. Xcode 15 by default installs only the iOS 17 SDK. You need to download the iOS 15 SDK from the Platforms preferences.